# Do I need to automate an app that Scan a QR, Is there an Appium function to send a specific QR from JAVA?

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I have an app that scan a QR code.
Scenario:

1. Go to the app
2. Click on Scan button
3. Open the camera to scan a QR code

My question is: Can I "Emulate" the QR with Appium?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a

> QR code. Scenario

that needs to make sure that the end to end functioning of software is working fine, or specific business process flow of the software is working fine - I would say, that this should be covered. Maybe, the correct question is, does this need to be automated?

I have done similar automated checks in JS, so I can only give you some design ideas. My scenario was involving a Barcode scanning in the middle of the test, so the way to achieve this without actual device, for me was to use [broadcast](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/10642/sending-broadcast). Sample code bellow:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a {your-app.action_scan} -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT --es com.symbol.datawedge.data_string {some-expected-string-as-barcode-value}
```

Note that this approach relies on testability, that is designed alongside the dev team. In my case, it was OK for them to allow and receive such event. It was tricky to sync the event and the test flow, but at the end we got good coverage of this major functional area.

Answer (score 0):

Following you can do scan:

- keep you phone on stand back side you can put the QR code whenever the camera open it will scan
- If that app supports the pick the QR code from gallery, you can pick from QR code picture from gallery

Since Appium interacting with UI, it doesn't have access internal  components.

Appium espresso might have the internal components like set drawable image and it comes with certain limitation